# Practice avoiding off-by-one errors?

Tags: loops, testing, off-by-one

I feel that I am quite bad at reasoning about boundary conditions in loops. I make a lot of mistakes and usually have off by one errors. Is there any way/site where i can practice problems related to corner cases/boundary conditions?